# Combining rows in R

Tags: r

I am working in R with a long dataframe but am having a bit of a problem. My dataframe is actually made up of two smaller dataframes. I then adapted the timeline from months to years so that the two share a common timeline.

However, the problem I am now facing is that sometimes I have two rows with the same time value (so one row for each questionnaire), but that I want to have only one row per time variable. (I attached a picture of what the problem looks like, that's probably more insightful than my explanation) Note that at this point, I do still want the dataframe to be in long format, but only want to get rid of the "extra rows".

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Attached also the head code, where nomem=ID, time.compressed=time, sel01-03=part of first questionnaire, close_num and gener_sat=part of second questionnaire.

`

```
structure(list(nomem_encr = c(800009L, 800009L, 800009L, 800012L, 
800015L, 800015L), timeline.compressed = c(79, 79, 95, 79, 28, 
28), sel01 = c(NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 7L), sel02 = c(NA, 6L, NA, 
NA, NA, 7L), sel03 = c(NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 5L), sel04 = c(NA, 
6L, NA, NA, NA, 6L), close_num = c(1, NA, 0.2, 1, 0.8, NA), gener_sat = c(7L, 
NA, 7L, 8L, 7L, NA)), .Names = c("nomem_encr", "timeline.compressed", 
"sel01", "sel02", "sel03", "sel04", "close_num", "gener_sat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))
```

`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p038.png

Comment: Can you also provide sample data. Using `head` to create a subset and `dput` to show us how to replicate it

Comment: In response to your first comment: I am afraid I don't understand your comment completely. I guess for every row, either the X variables are answered or the Y variables. However, sometimes two rows have the same time variable, i.e., the X and Y variables were answered at the same time. What I want is to combine those rows into one row in which both the X and the Y variables are answered.

Comment: How do we knoe which rows you'd have to be pruned?

Comment: @jaySf The rows that I want to be combined are those that have overlapping timeline.compressed values!

Comment: What happens to the NA's in row 3, where `nomem_enr == 800009` and `timeline.compressed == 95`? Do you want those remain NA in the final output?

Answer (score 0):

## Using the reshape2 and dplyr packages

Load libraries and data:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

x <- structure(
  list(
    nomem_encr = c(800009L, 800009L, 800009L, 800012L, 800015L, 800015L),
    timeline.compressed = c(79, 79, 95, 79, 28,  28),
    sel01 = c(NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 7L),
    sel02 = c(NA, 6L, NA,  NA, NA, 7L),
    sel03 = c(NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 5L),
    sel04 = c(NA,  6L, NA, NA, NA, 6L),
    close_num = c(1, NA, 0.2, 1, 0.8, NA),
    gener_sat = c(7L,  NA, 7L, 8L, 7L, NA)
  ), 
  .Names = c(
    "nomem_encr", "timeline.compressed",
    "sel01", "sel02", "sel03", "sel04", "close_num", "gener_sat"
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, 6L)
)
x
```

Here is what your data looks like:

```
  nomem_encr timeline.compressed sel01 sel02 sel03 sel04 close_num gener_sat
1     800009                  79    NA    NA    NA    NA       1.0         7
2     800009                  79     6     6     3     6        NA        NA
3     800009                  95    NA    NA    NA    NA       0.2         7
4     800012                  79    NA    NA    NA    NA       1.0         8
5     800015                  28    NA    NA    NA    NA       0.8         7
6     800015                  28     7     7     5     6        NA        NA
```

Now let's melt the data into long form:

```
melt(data = x, id.vars = c("nomem_encr", "timeline.compressed")) %>%
head(15)
```

Output:

```
   nomem_encr timeline.compressed variable value
1      800009                  79    sel01    NA
2      800009                  79    sel01     6
3      800009                  95    sel01    NA
4      800012                  79    sel01    NA
5      800015                  28    sel01    NA
6      800015                  28    sel01     7
7      800009                  79    sel02    NA
8      800009                  79    sel02     6
9      800009                  95    sel02    NA
10     800012                  79    sel02    NA
11     800015                  28    sel02    NA
12     800015                  28    sel02     7
13     800009                  79    sel03    NA
14     800009                  79    sel03     3
15     800009                  95    sel03    NA
```

If we cast the melted dataframe, the default behavior is to count how many entries we have for each item:

```
melt(data = x, id.vars = c("nomem_encr", "timeline.compressed")) %>%
  dcast(
    formula = nomem_encr + timeline.compressed ~ variable
  )
```

Output:

```
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
  nomem_encr timeline.compressed sel01 sel02 sel03 sel04 close_num gener_sat
1     800009                  79     2     2     2     2         2         2
2     800009                  95     1     1     1     1         1         1
3     800012                  79     1     1     1     1         1         1
4     800015                  28     2     2     2     2         2         2
```

We have 2 entries for the item identified by `800009 79` (using `nomem_encr` and `timeline.compressed` as the identifying variables).

We can change the default behavior to something else like `sum`:

```
melt(data = x, id.vars = c("nomem_encr", "timeline.compressed")) %>%
  dcast(
    formula = nomem_encr + timeline.compressed ~ variable,
    fun.aggregate = function(xs) sum(xs, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Output:

```
  nomem_encr timeline.compressed sel01 sel02 sel03 sel04 close_num gener_sat
1     800009                  79     6     6     3     6       1.0         7
2     800009                  95     0     0     0     0       0.2         7
3     800012                  79     0     0     0     0       1.0         8
4     800015                  28     7     7     5     6       0.8         7
```

Comment: UPDATE: I just noticed that when I use this code, it returns my data in zeroes, ones and occiasional twos, instead of what the actual values were. I copy-pasted your syntax and applied it to the whole data set. Any idea what may go wrong? Additionally, I get this error: Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length

Comment: structure(list(nomem_encr = c(800009L, 800009L, 800012L, 800015L, 
800015L, 800015L), timeline.compressed = c(79, 95, 79, 28, 40, 
52), sel01 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), sel02 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L), sel03 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), close_num = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), gener_sat = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("nomem_encr", 
"timeline.compressed", "sel01", "sel02", "sel03", "close_num", 
"gener_sat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))

Comment: You have multiple entries for each item, and the default behavior for `dcast` is to count how many items you have for each entry (0, 1, or 2 entries for a particular item).

You might also consider going back one step to the previous format of the data, and starting from there.

I updated my answer to show more details, and I hope that helps you to find a solution.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out the problem was that I had another timeline variable which also overlapped, but not to the same extent that timeline.compressed does. After leaving that variable out, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(nomem_encr, timeline.compressed) %>%
  summarize_all(funs(sort(.)[1]))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   nomem_encr [?]
  nomem_encr timeline.compressed sel01 sel02 sel03 sel04 close_num gener_sat
       <int>               <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>     <int>
1     800009                  79     6     6     3     6       1.0         7
2     800009                  95    NA    NA    NA    NA       0.2         7
3     800012                  79    NA    NA    NA    NA       1.0         8
4     800015                  28     7     7     5     6       0.8         7
```

If you want to replace the NA's with zero's, you can do the following:

```
df %>%
  group_by(nomem_encr, timeline.compressed) %>%
  summarize_all(funs(sort(.)[1])) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   nomem_encr [3]
  nomem_encr timeline.compressed sel01 sel02 sel03 sel04 close_num gener_sat
       <int>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     800009                  79     6     6     3     6       1.0         7
2     800009                  95     0     0     0     0       0.2         7
3     800012                  79     0     0     0     0       1.0         8
4     800015                  28     7     7     5     6       0.8         7
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(nomem_encr = c(800009L, 800009L, 800009L, 800012L, 
800015L, 800015L), timeline.compressed = c(79, 79, 95, 79, 28, 
28), sel01 = c(NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 7L), sel02 = c(NA, 6L, NA, 
NA, NA, 7L), sel03 = c(NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 5L), sel04 = c(NA, 
6L, NA, NA, NA, 6L), close_num = c(1, NA, 0.2, 1, 0.8, NA), gener_sat = c(7L, 
NA, 7L, 8L, 7L, NA)), .Names = c("nomem_encr", "timeline.compressed", 
"sel01", "sel02", "sel03", "sel04", "close_num", "gener_sat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))
```